# Drag and drop to MATLAB command window

Tags: matlab, drag-and-drop

When a file is dragged-and-dropped from the operating system to the MATLAB command window, MATLAB runs the **uiopen** command to import the data file. Depending on the file type, this may result in the import tool being displayed. In other cases, it leads to direct importing of the data in the file.

Is it possible to customize this process based on the file type? Perhaps I can hook into the drag-and-drop event itself or extend uiopen or extend the import tool or something else...?

Comment: I would try to modify the `uiopen.m` file in order to have it works the way you want.

Comment: you might be interested in this: http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/matlab-dde-support/

Comment: MATLAB IDE is java-based, so perhaps you can hook into the drag-drop event of the underlying Java components of the IDE... This sounds like something that [@YairAltman](http://stackoverflow.com/users/233829/yair-altman) would know about :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up accomplishing this by editing **uiimport.m**. Added the following after the `import` statements:

```
if nargin == 1
    possibleDroppedFile = varargin{1};
    if isstring( possibleDroppedFile ) ...
            && exist( possibleDroppedFile , 'file') == 2
        fileContent = myFileParser( possibleDroppedFile );
        assignin( 'base', 'fileContent', fileContent );
        return;
    end
end
```

Of course, how you parse the file is specific to your application but this gives you the gist.